# why logback sometimes output extra blank lines

Tags: java, logging, logback

i am using logback as a log framwork in my spring-boot application,it runs well before, but today something werid happend.it output extra blank lines on the console and logfile. i did not write those code to order the logger instance to ouput , but it did itself. it is still outputing extra log content. and it seems there were no log content loss.

and you can see from the timestamp,the blank lines are so close.

the size of log.file is over 30MB.

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

    <springProperty scope="context" name="fileName" source="spring.application.name" defaultValue="jackass"/>

    <!--定义日志文件的存储地址 勿在 LogBack 的配置中使用相对路径？项目的根路径下的log文件夹，可以使用绝对路径-->
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="log"/>
    <property name="LOG_NAME" value="${fileName}"/>


    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter"/>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex"
                    converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter"/>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx"
                    converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter"/>
    <!--可以引用的属性-->
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>

    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- 控制台输出 -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <!--格式化输出：%d表示日期，%thread表示线程名，%-5level：级别从左显示5个字符宽度 %msg：日志消息，%logger{50}  表示类名路径显示50字符。超过则只显示首字母 %n是换行符-->
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- 按照每天生成日志文件 -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!--日志文件输出的文件名-->
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/${LOG_NAME}%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/%d{HH-mm-ss}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <!--日志文件保留天数-->
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <!--格式化输出：%d表示日期，%thread表示线程名，%-5level：级别从左显示5个字符宽度%msg：日志消息，%n是换行符-->
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <!--日志文件最大的大小-->
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>500MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- 异步输出 -->
    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <!-- 不丢失日志.默认的,如果队列的80%已满,则会丢弃TRACT、DEBUG、INFO级别的日志 -->
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <!-- 更改默认的队列的深度,该值会影响性能.默认值为256 -->
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <!-- 添加附加的appender,最多只能添加一个 -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- 日志输出级别,可以在配置文件中修改 -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.dc.crawl" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

**log.file**

```
2020-05-06 10:16:35.328  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 更新订单信息成功 ：2020-05-05 16:00:47 ; GW2020050501743252
2020-05-06 10:16:39.712  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:40.040  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 更新订单信息成功 ：2020-05-05 23:58:47 ; GW2020050501496179
2020-05-06 10:16:45.156  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:45.234  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:46.061  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 更新订单信息成功 ：2020-05-05 23:07:25 ; GW2020050501464221
2020-05-06 10:16:55.577  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:55.671  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:55.718  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:55.983  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:56.061  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:56.123  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:56.170  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:56.233  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:56.482  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 
2020-05-06 10:16:59.243  INFO 1364 --- [pool-1-thread-16] c.d.c.crawler.impl.PlapOrderSynCrawler   : 更新订单信息成功 ：2020-05-05
```